# How to put multiple partials in one page? MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm only starting in MVC4 and 
I'm trying  to put multiple partial views in one page every partial is suppose to be with different data but it is always show one partial with only one data 
every partial is shown on button click.

This is the view code:

```
            <section id="comments">
            <h3>Comments</h3>
             @{

                 foreach (MvcApplication4.Models.comment item in postComments)
                 {
                            <article>

                                 <p>@item.body</p>

              using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", null, new { id = item.ID ,pid = item.idPost}, FormMethod.Post))
                 {
                     @Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete)
                      <button type="submit" class="button delete" >Delete</button>
                                          }

                  <section>
                        <button type="submit" class="button Edit"  id="edit" onclick="return showHide();"  >Edit</button>

                        <div  id="partial" hidden="hidden">
                              @Html.Partial("editCom",item)
                            </div>
                  </section>
               }
           }
             </article>

         }
       }
       </section>
```

This is the showhide partial:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">// <![CDATA[
       function showHide() { 
           var ele = document.getElementById("partial");
           if(ele.style.display == "block") {
               ele.style.display = "none";
           }
           else {
               ele.style.display = "block";
           }
       }
       // ]]></script>
```

This is the partial :

```
@using MvcApplication4.Models
@model MvcApplication4.Models.comment       


    @{comment com = Model;
        }
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", null,new{ pid=com.idPost,cid=com.ID}, FormMethod.Post))
                                              {
                <fieldset>
                           <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => com.user)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
             @Html.LabelFor(x => com.user,Session["username"].ToString())
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => com.user)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => com.email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => com.email,com.email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => com.email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => com.url)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => com.url,com.url)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => com.url)
        </div>
         <div class="editor-label">
         @Html.LabelFor(x => com.body)
        </div>

         <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.EditorFor(x => com.body,com.body)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => com.body)
        </div>
                    <p>
            <input type="submit" value="save"  /> 

        </p>   
                </fieldset>
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for

```
<div  id="partial" hidden="hidden">
    @Html.Partial("editCom",item)
</div>
```

Determines which sections are controled by the buttons:

```
var ele = document.getElementById("partial");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
    ele.style.display = "none";
}
....
```

You are generating several sections all with the same id of "partial" then expecting the button to determine which div to manage without a unique id of some kind via `getElementById("partial")`

Instead, you need to generate a unique id for each `<div>` and then use the same id in your javascript method for `getElementById()`